# Qt Crash when initializing QGuiApplication object under Windows ARM64

Tags: windows, qt, qt5, arm64

I built Qt 5.15.7 myself for Windows ARM64 using a patch.

I have this crash when the QGuiApplication object is getting initialized under Windows, ARM64, using Visual Studio 2022.

Do you have any advice on how this could be fixed?

[image: desc 1]
[image: desc 2]
[image: desc 3]
[image: desc 4]
[image: desc 5]
[image: desc 6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I turned to using Qt 6.3.1 instead, which solved this crash for Windows ARM64.

(Thanks god I am using CMake + Conan so I have the ability to easily use different Qt version for
Windows(10-11) Arm64
and
Windows(7-8-10-11) x86/x64.)